# Click on div to open submenus Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have 5 categories that are currently displayed none. Im trying to get them to appear when a user clicks on a div that is above the displayed none div. I have written some code that Ive used on another project but this time the console is bringing back that its not a function? Below is just one of the categories that I to show. What I have written is options__container set to display none. When a user clicks on question__container, to set options__container to display block. Any tips are greatly appreciated

```
<main class="subscription__container">
      <section
        id="preferences"
        class="subscription__container--preferences box"
      >
        <div class="question__container">
          <h3 class="question__container--title">
            How do you drink your coffee?
          </h3>
          <img
            class="question__container--img"
            src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
            alt="arrow"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="options__container">
          <div class="options__container--option">
            <input
              id="capsule"
              type="radio"
              data-preference="Capsule"
              value="Capsule"
              name="preferences"
              checked
            />
            <label for="capsule"></label>
            <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
            <p class="options__container--description">
              Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="options__container--option">
            <input
              id="filter"
              type="radio"
              data-preference="Filter"
              value="Filter"
              name="preferences"
            />
            <label for="filter"></label>
            <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
            <p class="options__container--description">
              For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="options__container--option">
            <input
              id="espresso"
              type="radio"
              data-preference="Espresso"
              value="Espresso"
              name="preferences"
            />
            <label for="espresso"></label>
            <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
            <p class="options__container--description">
              Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful
              experience.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

```
.options__container {
  display: none;
  &--option {
    width: 328px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: $bigselection-default;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &--title {
    font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  &--description {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 278px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  }
}
.options__container.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```
const questionBox = document.getElementsByClassName("question__container");
questionBox.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(
      ".options__container"
    );
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

Comment: parent isn't high enough since the options container is a sibling of the parent. Try using `closest('section').querySelector()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following changes to make it run

- `getElementByClassName` will return array-like data structure and it doesn't have `forEach` method. So need to convert it into an array if you gonna use `forEach`.

you can do something like

```
[...questionBox].forEach((el)
```

or you can also use `querySelectorAll` to select all elements like

```
const questionBox = document.querySelectorAll(".question__container");
```

- You need to select `section` with id `preferences` to select the `options__container` using `querySelector`

You can easily do this by selecting `parentElement` of `parentElement`

```
event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".options__container");
```

```js
const questionBox = document.getElementsByClassName("question__container");
[...questionBox].forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(
      ".options__container"
    );
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

```css
.options__container {
  display: none;
}

.options__container--option {
  width: 328px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.options__container--title {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.options__container--description {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  width: 278px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
}

.options__container.open {
  display: block;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style2.css.map */
```

```html
<main class="subscription__container">
  <section id="preferences" class="subscription__container--preferences box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How do you drink your coffee?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="capsule" type="radio" data-preference="Capsule" value="Capsule" name="preferences" checked />
        <label for="capsule"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="filter" type="radio" data-preference="Filter" value="Filter" name="preferences" />
        <label for="filter"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="espresso" type="radio" data-preference="Espresso" value="Espresso" name="preferences" />
        <label for="espresso"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful experience.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you, I MUST learn more about dom events. After this project ill be learning domevents.dev

Comment: Should be `const subMenu = event.target.parentNode.nextSibling;`, so OP is not just getting the first one every time.

Comment: @StackSlave we can also use `event.target.parentElement.parentElement`. Thatt's OP choice

Comment: If that was a larger list OP would still be getting only the first `.options__container`, using `.querySelector`, so that won't work in all cases.

Comment: I agree what if there is a larger list that contain and `options__container` is not next to `question__container`

Comment: Can alternatively change `getElementByClassName` to `querySelectorAll` to receive an array for `forEach`.

Comment: I guess I'm just unsure if OP has multiple questions in `.subscription__container--preferences box`. If not, your code works... but I would refrain from using `.getElementsByClassName` since it returns a live collection, which might have unintended consequences. `.querySelectorAll` is preferred.

Comment: @StackSlave Edited answer